# Eclipse RCP - Perspective -layout.setfixed(true) not working in Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

We have developed an eclipse rcp application using 3.5 and are trying to move it to 4.2.1.

It is a simple RCP application with a view. On doing the basics and launching it I found that the Perspective.java-> layout.setFixed(true) is not working anymore. Since it was a single view application, it didnt require re-sizing, hence we did not want the coolbar with close/max/min buttons here, hence had used the API.

But with the new Eclipse (Eclipse 4.2.1), the toolbar with maximize-minimize button (just above the view) is visible even when this method is called.
I found some discussion on this issue here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331402 but I am not sure if this is a problem and if so, when and if this would get fixed with Eclipse 4.

I appreciate any kind of help I can get here.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct bug, and it was fixed in 4.3 (Kepler).

Comment: Hi Paul I checked the application using Kepler (4.3) and found that my view doesn't have max/min buttons but but there is a empty frame above my view which seems to be re-size able and blank (with max/min) buttns on them. Any idea what could be wrong here.